# Why is my python code adding multiple integers into the list

Tags: python

I'm writing a program that has you enter in as many inputs as you would like, and uses an empty space to end the inputs. Once all inputs are entered, it's supposed to take those inputs and put them inside lists that will then print all negatives on the left side, then all zeros, then all the positive integers on the right. I'm unable to use the sort function because it want's the integers to appear as enterred, just sorted by negatives, zeros, and positives. My code sorts them but once it prints and adds the lists together into one, it duplicates many of the integers, sometimes even multiple times. I can't see why it's doing this.

```
numbers = []
negatives = []
zeros = []
positives = []
while True:
    integers = input("Please enter an integer. Enter a blank line to exit: ")
    if integers == '':
        break
    else:
        integers = int(integers)
        numbers.append(integers)
        for value in numbers:
            if value < 0:
                negatives.append(value)
            elif value == 0:
                zeros.append(value)
            elif value > 0:
                positives.append(value)
            else:
                print("Error")
print(f"You entered in {numbers}")
print(f"sorted, your numbers are: {negatives + zeros + positives}")
```

Here is my code. Your help would be appreciated

Comment: because you're iterating over the whole list every time you add an integer with `for value in numbers`. When you're doing `integers = int(integers)` that's named wrong because you can have at most 1 integer in that variable. Remove the `for` loop and change it to `value = integers` and your code should work the way you expect.

Comment: Looks like you are getting an integer from the call to `input(....)`, but then appending that integer to the list `numbers`.  Then, you iterate `numbers`, which will revisit every number that was previously added to `numbers` every time you iterate it.

Comment: Move the for loop completely out of the while loop.

Comment: Or yea, de-dent the for loop 2 times.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `for value in numbers`:

```
numbers = []
negatives = []
zeros = []
positives = []
while True:
    integers = input("Please enter an integer. Enter a blank line to exit: ")
    if integers == '':
        break
    else:
        try:
          integers = int(integers)
        except ValueError:
          print("Error")
        numbers.append(integers)

        if integers < 0:
            negatives.append(integers)
        elif integers == 0:
            zeros.append(integers)
        elif integers > 0:
            positives.append(integers)

print(f"You entered in {numbers}")
print(f"sorted, your numbers are: {negatives + zeros + positives}")
```